# Creating Anaconda environment satisfying prerequisites below

Tags: python, anaconda, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, torch

I have installed conda 4.5.12 and managed to install an environment with a .yml file flawlessly.

Now I need to set an up environment to supply myself a simulation of this project in here.

In it's prerequisites list there are these components;

- Python 2: HDF5, OpenCV 2 interfaces for python.
- C++: HDF5, OpenCV 2, Boost
- Lua JIT and Torch 7.
- Torch 7 packages: class, GPU support cunn and cutorch, Matlab support mattorch, JSON support lunajson, Torch image library image
- Please note that mattorch is an outdated packages which is no longer maintained.

So my question is mainly whether I can generate a yaml file to cover up this list & create an virtual environment to start up development while researching about.

You can find the Git Hub branch in [[HERE]](https://github.com/simonwsw/deep-soli)

Answer (score 1):

If all these packages are available on conda or pipy, then you can indeed just make a yml and install that.

From personal experience, it's often a good idea to gradually add packages and often test installing the conda environment. In this way, you can better identify if a dependency conflict arrises and you need to set some manual versions.